# How to write $(2n-1) (2n-2) (2n-3) (2n-4)$ in terms of $n$ factorials

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to get the final equations in terms of $n$, for example $n = 3$, then the equation is: $(2n-1) * (2n-2) * (2n-3)$, if $n = 4$, then the equation is: $(2n-1) (2n-2) (2n-3) (2n-4)$.

Comment: $\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n-5)!}$ Although I woudn't call this "simplification" :)

Comment: my bad, I want to get the final equations in terms of n, for example n = 3, then the equation is : (2n-1) * (2n-2) * (2n-3), if n = 4, then the equation is : (2n-1) * (2n-2) * (2n-3)* (2n-4)

Comment: $\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!}$

Comment: thank you! how did you get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to write the expression
$$
(n)(n+1)...(2n-1)
$$
in a simpler form. Notice that
$$
(2n-1)!=(1)(2)...(2n-1)
$$
while
$$
(n-1)!=(1) (2)... (n-1)
$$
so
$$
\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!}=(n)(n+1)...(2n-1).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's adress some cases:

- n:=1 : n
  (One term, given by (2n-1), reduces to 1 which was your n)
- n:=2 : n(n+1)
  (Two terms, (2n-1)(2n-2), reduces to $3*2$ which is n(n+1)
- n:=3 : n(n+1)(n+2)
  (Three terms, (2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3), reduces to $5*4*3$,  a pattern, so

...

- n:=n : n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n-1), using this pattern in terms of n as desired.

Note that when n is also the number of multiplicative elements, the last element (2n-n) is exactly n.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you, I edit the question, but I still don't understand how to get (2−1)! / (−1)!